# How to access data from a post response in JSON format

Tags: python, json, list, post, python-requests

I am trying to access a dictionary that has been returned after making a post to an API, but I am having difficulty formatting the data with JSON.

It seems to be returning the data as a dictionary but I receive the error 'list indices must be integers or slices, not str' which makes me believe that it is just returning a list that looks like a dictionary.  I have tried using json.loads() and trying to access the data through lists but I can't seem to get it.  The data I am trying to has multiple sub dictionaries/lists.

```py
resp = post(url = endpoint_url, data = data, headers = headers)
data_for_process = resp.json()
print(data_for_process['pages']['keyValuePairs']['key'])
```

I expected the print statement to return the value for that specific key but I get the error instead.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Your response is stored in `data_for_process` but you are trying to access `data`

Comment: that was actually a mistake in the post, i am calling the correct object.  I changed some variable names when copying it over here

Comment: One of the fields (pages,keyValuePairs,key) is a list and therefore you beed to use an integer. Example (assuming pages is a list) `data_for_process['pages'][0]['keyValuePairs']['key']`

Comment: This was it, a combination of lists and dictionaries. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use the json library of python

```
import json
import pprint

resp = post(url = endpoint_url, data = data, headers = headers)
resp_json = json.loads(resp.content)
pprint.pprint(resp_json) # to display the dict prettier
```

Comment: Explenation for future readers is appreciated. Now your answer is flagged as low quality and I assume that's not what you had in mind. Please update it.